# What is the shortest way to convert string characters into an array of characters in Perl?

Tags: perl

If I've the string "abcd", what's the shortest way to convert in @arr containing qw(a b c d)?

Comment: Another question might be why do you need to split a string of characters into an array of characters?  For most things in other languages that require an array of characters, there's a single function that sidesteps that need in Perl.

Comment: I want to extract any char at an index just like as we do for an array while within any expression

Comment: use substr, but be careful to grab entire graphemes instead of single code points.

Comment: the function you need is called substr (with a length of 1): `substr(STRING, INDEX, 1)`

Comment: substr() is a poor choice for UTF-8 strings. It's very slow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
my @arr = split //, "abcd";

my @arr = "abcd" =~ /./sg;

my @arr = unpack '(a)*', 'abcd';
```

Comment: Thanks but if I want 2nd char in the string "abcd" then I'd be writing in an expression: ((split //."abcd")[1]). Could it be simpler than this? In case of a function: to_arr($str)[2] may be bit shorter?

Comment: @user656848, `substr("abcd", 1, 1)`

Comment: @user656848, `to_arr($str)[2]` isn't valid and uses the wrong index. You'd need `( to_arr($str) )[1]`. It's called a "list slice".

Comment: Sorry to_arr($str)[2] should be to_arr($str)[1]. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @ikegami substr("abcd",1,1)  is better and simple

Comment: @user656848: If you just want the second character then why are you asking how to convert a string into an array of characters?

Comment: It could be any index and not just index 2.

Comment: @user656848, Again, `to_arr($str)[1]` won't work. You'd need `( to_arr($str) )[1]`.

Comment: @user656848: You can get a single character at any index without turning the string into an array by using `substr`. This will also be much more efficient than chopping the string up, storing the individual characters in memory, and then throwing all but one of them away.

Comment: I'll go by  substr("abcd",1,1)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is with split with a regex that matches anything.

```
my @arr = split //, "abcd";
```

Comment: I need to extract a char in an expression. Then I'll need to do lot of wrapping in parantheses as in your example Colin. I think using a function like to_arr($str)[index] will be simpler.